# Preserve 3-dimensionality when converting PIL image to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have a list of PIL images: p0, p1, ..., p85999 (a total of 86000 of them). They are all RGB, of size 30x30px.

I need to convert them to normalized numpy arrays, I did the following:

`[np.asarray(r).astype('float32') / 255.0) for r in images]`

where `r` is a PIL image.

This gives an array of numpy arrays.

However, these arrays are sometimes of shape `(30,30,3)` and sometimes of shape `(30,30)`.

I want them **always** to be of shape `(30,30,3)`.

I'm guessing numpy does this for performance reasons (when RGB is not
needed, eg. white images?).

Anyway, how to get the desired result - get all numpy arrays to be of size  `(30,30,3)`?

Also, ideally I would want my final numpy array to be of size `(30, 30, 3, 86000)`. Is there a shortcut to create such an array straight from PIL images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing numpy does this for performance reasons

Numpy has nothing to do with it, this is your PIL Image having one channel only.
The simplest solution is to just `convert` everything to RGB:

```
ims = [np.asarray(r.convert('RGB')).astype('float32') / 255.0) for r in images]
```

If you then call `np.asarray(ims)`, you'll obtain an array of shape `[N,30,30,3]` where N is the number of images, which you can then `transpose` to your desired ordering.

Comment: However, when I call `np.asarray(ims)`, I get an array of shape `(N,2)` instead of the desired `(N,30,30,3)`.

Comment: What's the shape of `ims[0]`?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I messed up somewhere else. What you wrote is correct.